# TypeScript is not throwing on child constraint

Tags: reactjs, typescript

can't figure out why TypeScript is not throwing an error when I am including the anchor element inside my component.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-starter-typescript-vgkvsw?file=App.tsx,index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';

export type CacodemonSpecialProps = React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'span'> & {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  specialProperty?: string;
};

export const CacodemonSpecial = ({
  children,
}: CacodemonSpecialProps): JSX.Element => {
  return <span>{children}</span>;
};

export type CacodemonProps = React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'button'> & {
  onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
  children?: CacodemonSpecialProps | CacodemonSpecialProps[];
};

export const Cacodemon = ({
  children,
  onClick,
}: CacodemonProps): JSX.Element => {
  return <button onClick={onClick}>{children}</button>;
};

export function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Cacodemon</h1>
      <Cacodemon onClick={() => alert('Clicked')}>
        <CacodemonSpecial>Doom</CacodemonSpecial>
        <a>This element should error in TypeScript! But it doesn't!</a>
      </Cacodemon>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Wish there was an easier solution but typing children is a nightmare: https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/advanced/patterns_by_usecase/#typing-children

Comment: Why do you think it should error? Also, you should know that rendered JSX is always typed as `JSX.Element`, (see https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChTMBXAOw2AmrgFkBPAYVzAAoBKOAb1JxhcIjEpRGAHgAWARgB8cgEwBmKQHp5C0gF9yaBgGd4KOAF44U1h3BwNOjRpFwAegH4Dx+ACMLVlAUURjMYFABzTUDSJxcPIA) so the contents of what was rendered is unknown to the type system.

Comment: @AlexWayne Yea was pretty much trying to see if you can specific types on rendered elements. Saw this PR and was investigating: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/51328

Comment: That PR doesn't change that rendered JSX (meaning angle brackets `<></>`) will always be a `JSX.Element`.